# ArcCatalog File Navigation slower than Windows Explorer

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, arccatalog, arcgis-10.6, windows-10

I am currently using ArcMap 10.6 and have been having issues navigating to files within ArcCatalog. It has been taking me about 10-15 seconds to open folders in ArcCatalog when it only takes a fraction of a second to open the same folder in Windows Explorer.

Does anyone know the reason for this lag?

Comment: Windows Explorer isn't polling each object to determine how it should be represented (point, line, poly, file geodatabase, coverage,...)

Comment: Having any detail columns turned on also takes a huge toll, especially on network volumes.

Comment: The speed you are experience is about par for the course. We all have to live with it.